# Android Layout beneath Action Bar

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar

I want to make a screen with multiple buttons, however, it keeps coming out something like this with the buttons under the action bar.[Wrong Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wMAc.png) The buttons are added later programmatically to `LinearLayout`.

The xml file looks like **activity_main.xml**:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="672dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="606dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:onClick="newScheme"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.997"
        tools:ignore="OnClick" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I get the buttons beneath the action bar instead of under it?

Comment: can You add `content_main` file?

Comment: I added the `content_main` file

Comment: Okay, and You add buttons to `linearLayout` in `content_main `?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are added programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created something like this but I changed some hardcoded sizes (I don't know what You do but I think usually it's not a good practice).

**Main XML**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 4" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:onClick="newScheme"
        android:tag="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="OnClick" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here I added buttons but if You add it programmatically just delete it.

**And an effect:**

[image]